# wget.exe Can't save page at virustotal.com

Tags: html, windows, save, wget

I've build personal antivirus which needs to save result page from virustotal.com in my drive, I did use wget.exe for this job as third part, but it keeps showing this error with [0/0] saved:

```
    C:\wget\GnuWin32\bin>wget.exe --no-check-certificate https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/15c34d2b0e834727949dbacea897db33c785a32ac606c0935e3758c8dc975535/analysis/
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrcsyswgetrc = C:\wget\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc--2015-11-30 06:39:03--  https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/15c34d2b0e834727949dbacea897db33c785a32ac606c0935e3758c8dc975535/analysis/
Resolving www.virustotal.com... 127.8.0.1
Connecting to www.virustotal.com|127.8.0.1|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify www.virustotal.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=GeoT
rust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 0 [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html.2'

    [ <=>                                   ] 0           --.-K/s   in 0s

2015-11-30 06:39:05 (0.00 B/s) - `index.html.2' saved [0/0]


C:\wget\GnuWin32\bin>
```

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Virustotal has an API designed to do what you want, they provide python examples for this:

```
import simplejson
import urllib
import urllib2
url = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report"
parameters = {"resource": "99017f6eebbac24f351415dd410d522d",  
              "apikey": "1fe0ef5feca2f84eb450bc3617f839e317b2a686af4d651a9bada77a522201b0"}
data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
json = response.read()
print json
```

(All code taken from https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report)

It is very likely that because of this what you are trying to do is not working. The site returns a `Content-Length` of `0` when you use the URL you see in the browser (which uses a lot of Javascripts to do its work)